# How to emit an event on the frame element when navigateTo is happening in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have something like this in my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <Page>
    <ActionBar title="myapp">
      <NavigationButton text="<" @tap="goBack"></NavigationButton>
      <label class="txt-lg" text="myapp" />
    </ActionBar>
    <DockLayout stretchLastChild="true">
      <StackLayout dock="bottom">
        <navBar />
      </StackLayout>
      <frame id="content">
        <home />
      </frame>
    </DockLayout>
  </Page>
</template>
```

And then in my navBar I have 4 items that are my four pages.
I use `this.$navigateTo` to navigate between the pages whenever a navigation button is pressed, also I have two other pages that I might navigate to which are not listed in the navBar and have their own buttons in some other places.
also There is one instance where I do a navigation while I'm in a popup.(e.g. I'm in home, I open a popup, I press a button, and then the popup is closed but I'm not back in home, and I'm in faq instead which is another item from the navBar)

Basically what I want is this:
I want the navBar to know the name of the component that is rendered inside the frame with id="content" right now, if the name of that component is either of "home" "faq" "stats" "profile" it should make the corresponding icon bold, otherwise no icon should be bold.
I don't necessarily want to use the component name. I just wanna have this work!

Comment: Why don't you simply use an EventBus, emit events from child components and listen to same from parent.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks. I did that. What are some other best practices for this sort of thing?